ADC/DAC system clock frequency for sampling rate
I'm doing some audio system with ADC/DAC used. Desired sampling rate is 48 kHz, but now I’m stuck with required system clock frequency for sample rate.
The ADC I use is PCM1804.
I want to use it in slave mode, as I understand sampling frequency is controlled by SCKI (system clock input) and OSR (oversampling ratio) pins, I leave tables below.
I don't understand what means automatically detected when for example SCKI is 12.288 MHz and over sampling ratio is single rate because then system clock rata can be identified as 256 fs and 384 fs for both sampling ratio 32 kHz and 48 kHz.
My question is how to calculate required system clock frequency for 48 kHz, same question for DAC's because there i see same logic where i can choose only oversampling ratio modes (single rate, dual rate, and quad rate).


The table 3 is clear. Use any of the system clocks that make up the 48 kHz sampling rate.
The higher system clock you use will still divide automatically down to  oversampling mode that allows for the 48 kHz rate.
And for 48 kHz rate, only single oversampling mode is possible as 48 kHz is not listed elsewhere. This makes the modulator run at 128x rate.
It is consistent with the fact that the minimum clock is 256xFs or 12.288 MHz will result into 48 kHz in single mode.
You can use higher clocks, but they are automatically detected and divided down so if you set single rate you get 48 kHz out.
And, additionally, since the chip is in slave mode, it receives the sampling rate wordsync/LRCLK from somewhere which it can use to detect if you use 12.288 MHz for 48 or 32 kHz sampling.
